# Why is use of HFS+ disks so complex and demanding in Linux?

Tags: linux, hfs+

There are tons of questions on how to mount, read, write HFS+ disks in linux.  Why?  What is the issue here that is leading to this particular format type being so poorly supported out of the box on linux?  Is it proprietary, or just unsupported?

**What are the major non-opinion road blocks here?**

Comment: I can't stop people from answering with opinions.  The question -- as asked -- should have factual answers.  Things like "proprietary apple format" are what I expect, but maybe it's just never been considered a priority for linux.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of hassle in this situation is the issue.  I'll change that word, and maybe it'll make more sense that this is a factual statement.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that helps me a bit, though I do wonder what specific complexities and demands you're referring to. Is there a common issue that you have in mind?

Comment: (you might notice I'm starting to clean up my comments, to keep your question's discussion short and on point)

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/0x09/hfsfuse or another method?